# how to add value to a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm working on a script where I have a list of tuples like `('1','2','3','4')`. e.g.:

```
list = [('1','2','3','4'),
        ('2','3','4','5'),
        ('3','4','5','6'),
        ('4','5','6','7')]
```

Now I need to add `'1234'`, `'2345'`,`'3456'` and `'4567'` respectively at the end of each tuple. e.g:

```
list = [('1','2','3','4','1234'),
        ('2','3','4','5','2345'),
        ('3','4','5','6','3456'),
        ('4','5','6','7','4567')]
```

Is it possible in any way?

Comment: At least in Python, tuples are immutable. If you want to "add something to a tuple", why not use a mutable data structure from the start?

Comment: I do it too -- most often with "file", because "for file in files" is so darn natural! -- but in general you should probably avoid calling your lists "list", which replaces the built-in "list".

Answer (score 169):

Tuples are immutable and not supposed to be changed - that is what the list type is for.

However, you can replace each tuple using `originalTuple + (newElement,)`, thus creating a new tuple. For example:

```
t = (1,2,3)
t = t + (1,)
print(t)
(1,2,3,1)
```

But I'd rather suggest to go with lists from the beginning, because they are faster for inserting items.

And another hint: Do not overwrite the built-in name `list` in your program, rather call the variable `l` or some other name. If you overwrite the built-in name, you can't use it anymore in the current scope.

Comment: A shorthand `t += 1,`

Comment: Excellent points, however, I am in the unfortunate situation where I want to iteratively add values to a `sqlite3` database and need to make a tuple of the values to add (since the required syntax is `VALUES (v1, v2, v3, ...)`. In this case, knowing how to add values to a tuple is very beneficial.

Answer (score 18):

Based on the syntax, I'm guessing this is Python. The point of a tuple is that it is immutable, so you need to replace each element with a new tuple:

```
list = [l + (''.join(l),) for l in list]
# output:
[('1', '2', '3', '4', '1234'), 
 ('2', '3', '4', '5', '2345'), 
 ('3', '4', '5', '6', '3456'), 
 ('4', '5', '6', '7', '4567')]
```

Comment: This works, sure. But should this really be done? I wonder. Because this defeats the purpose of having a tuple in the first place. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in other answers, tuples are immutable once created, and a list might serve your purposes better.

That said, another option for creating a new tuple with extra items is to use the splat operator:

`new_tuple = (*old_tuple, 'new', 'items')`

I like this syntax because it *looks* like a new tuple, so it clearly communicates what you're trying to do.

Using splat, a potential solution is:

`list = [(*i, ''.join(i)) for i in list]`

Comment: most pythonic!
This should be the top answer

Answer (score 9):

In Python, you can't. Tuples are immutable.

On the containing list, you could replace tuple `('1', '2', '3', '4')` with a different `('1', '2', '3', '4', '1234')` tuple though.

Answer (score 8):

As other people have answered, tuples in python are immutable and the only way to 'modify' one is to create a new one with the appended elements included.

But the best solution is a list.  When whatever function or method that requires a tuple needs to be called, create a tuple by using tuple(list).

Answer (score 5):

I was going through some details related to `tuple` and `list`, and what I understood is:

- Tuples are `Heterogeneous` collection data type
- Tuple has **Fixed length (per tuple type)**
- Tuple are **Always finite**

So for appending new item to a tuple, need to cast it to `list`, and do **`append()`** operation on it, then again cast it back to tuple.

> But personally what I felt about the Question is, if **Tuples** are supposed to be **finite**, **fixed length** items and if we are using those data types in our application logics then there should **not** be a scenario to appending new items OR updating an item value in it.
>   So instead of **list of tuples** it should be **list of list** itself, Am I right on this?

Comment: There are scenarios where you need to pass a tuple to a function, such as with SQL (psycopg2) or interacting with R (rpy2). The functions don't always work properly if given a list instead of a tuple. Sometimes you also receive a tuple from a function rather than a list. Tuples can guard against mistakenly modifying an original list when you should instead be working on a copy of a list. So yes, either directly or indirectly lists are intermediaries in the answers presented. However, casting back to a tuple at the end is still logical in many scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

```
    list_of_tuples = [('1', '2', '3', '4'),
                      ('2', '3', '4', '5'),
                      ('3', '4', '5', '6'),
                      ('4', '5', '6', '7')]


    def mod_tuples(list_of_tuples):
        for i in range(0, len(list_of_tuples)):
            addition = ''
            for x in list_of_tuples[i]:
                addition = addition + x
            list_of_tuples[i] = list_of_tuples[i] + (addition,)
        return list_of_tuples

    # check: 
    print mod_tuples(list_of_tuples)
```

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people is writing tuples are immutables... and that's right! But there is this code:

```
tuple = ()
for i in range(10):
    tuple += (i,)
print(tuple)
```

And It works! Why? Well.. that's because in the code there is a "=". Every time you use the operator "=" in Python you assign a new value to an object: you create a new variable!

So you are not modifying the old tuple: you are creating a new one, with the same name (tuple), with value the old one plus something more.

Answer (score 0):

```
OUTPUTS = []
for number in range(len(list_of_tuples))):
    tup_ = list_of_tuples[number]
    list_ = list(tup_)  
    item_ = list_[0] + list_[1] + list_[2] + list_[3]
    list_.append(item_)
    OUTPUTS.append(tuple(list_))
```

OUTPUTS is what you desire

Answer (score 0):

##### In case of tuple and list, a very simple way can be  (suppose) :

```
tpl = ( 3, 6, 9)
lst = [ 12, 15, 18]
my_tuple = tpl + tuple(lst)
print(my_tuple)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator so that you don't have to alter the underlying list or store a new one. Create it on the fly during your insert so you only loop once.

```
def my_generator(old_list: list, new_values: tuple):
    for idx, row in enumerate(old_list):
        new_row: list = list(row)

        new_row.append(new_values[idx])

        new_dataset: tuple = tuple(new_row)

        yield new_dataset

def make_sql():
    my_list: list = [
        ('1', '2', '3', '4'),
        ('2', '3', '4', '5'),
        ('3', '4', '5', '6'),
        ('4', '5', '6', '7')
    ]

    my_var: tuple = ('1234', '2345', '3456', '4567')

    my_new_list = my_generator(my_list, my_var)

    'I like SQL Injection attacks!'

    for row in my_new_list:
        print(
            'INSERT INTO users (V1, V2, V3, V4) '
            f'VALUES {row};'
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_sql()
```