# How to zip a list with a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list

Say I have the following lists:

```
list_a = [1, 4, 7]
list_b = [(2, 3), (5, 6), (8, 9)]
```

How do I combine them so that it becomes

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Comment: Do you mean that you can't use the `zip` function?

Comment: `[(a,) + b for a,b in zip(list_a, list_b)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add value to a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913397/how-to-add-value-to-a-tuple)

Answer (score 2):

You can expand the tuple in the second zipped item to build a final tuple

```
list_a = [1, 4, 7]
list_b = [(2, 3), (5, 6), (8, 9)]

print([(a,*b) for a,b in zip(list_a, list_b)])
```

Output

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = [1, 4, 7]
list_b = [(2, 3), (5, 6), (8, 9)]
# FOR LIST_A TO B
    
for i in range(len(list_a)):
    a = list_a[i]
    test = list_b[i] + (a,)
    print(test)
```